# Using setState as a callback in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this function, `saveUnsavedElements` which isn't currently working with its callback. I just want to flip this boolean when the dispatch finishes. I tried wrapping it in `{() => this.setState({hasUnsavedChanges: false}) }` but that didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
saveUnsavedElements() {
    const { elements } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    const updates = Object.keys(elements).map(key => {
         const { id, top, left } = elements[key];
         return { id, top, left };
    });

    dispatch(requestUpdateElements(updates, { this.setState({hasUnsavedChanges: false}) } );
    }
```

Comment: Why not keep this `hasUnsavedChanges` in your store so you can update that once you dispatch

Comment: Because then I'd have to rearchitect a bunch of my app :) going to keep that as-is for now but will consider the suggestion

Comment: Have you tried `() => {this.setState({hasUnsavedChanges: false}) }`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is what I needed to do. Hope this helps someone else out

`dispatch(requestUpdateElements(updates, () => this.setState({ hasUnsavedChanges: false })));`